# Do I need hyphens?

Tags: hyphenation

Which is correct?

1. "...during the entire hour and twelve minute lecture."

or

2. "...during the entire hour-and-twelve minute lecture."

Comment: Some would argue it should be *the entire hour-and-twelve-minute lecture*.

Comment: *Hour and twelve minutes* (and its hyphenated equivalent *hour-and-twelve-minute* [lecture]) is awkward; why not replace it by *seventy-two-minute lecture* ?

Answer (score 0):

***Hour-and-twelve-minute*** is an adjectival phrase describing 'lecture'.

It is simpler for a reader to see this if the words are hyphenated.

Answer (score -3):

"...during the entire hour and twelve minute**s** lecture.",  is the better one,

> The dash is a handy device, informal and essentially playful, telling you that you're about to take off on a different tack but still in some way connected with the present course — only you have to remember that the dash is there, and either put a second dash at the end of the notion to let the reader know that he's back on course, or else end the sentence, as here, with a period.
>   __ Lewis Thomas

Comment: This em dash is not related to hyphenating groups of words.

Comment: A ten dollars bill? A three miles journey?